# can't play ISO either on Ubuntu 14.04(laptop) or 12.04 (netbook)_mplayer, vlc do not play

Tags: vlc, iso, mplayer

I have two computers running Ubuntu (both dual boot with Windows 7):

- laptop Toshiba, 
  Processor: Intel Celeron CPU900 @2.20Ghz
  Graphics: Mobile Intel GM45 Express Chipset
  64-bit
- netbook Packard Bell:
  Processor: Intel atom CPU N450 @1.66Ghz x 2
  Graphics: Intel IGD x86/MMX/SSE
  32-bit

When I try to play an iso file on both of them, nothing happens. VLS and MPlayer open normally, I don't get any error messages, just nothing happens.

I did not rip the DVD myself. I just got the iso files (it is a language course).

Any help would be appreciates. I spent like 3 days trying to find the solution. No success so far.

---

I mounted the iso. But I get 4 folders which I don't know what to do with. My iso is an interactive language course. Looking into individual folders will not help me. My folders are: - data (with a list of files with .rsd extension) - documentation (a list of .pdf files) - languages (one .txt file) - speech (one .rsd file).

Now what?

What I understand is that "mounting" iso is not the same as "playing" iso.

Please advise.

Comment: This is a data DVD, not a video DVD, which is why your attempts to play it in VLC and MPlayer haven't succeeded. (If it had been an ISO for a video DVD, it would have worked and you wouldn't even have had to mount it. Fortunately, mounting it was useful anyway, as it revealed that it isn't a video DVD at all.) What are you trying to do? Are you trying to play specific videos from the ISO? If so, have you looked for video files in the `data` folder? Or are you trying to install and run the software itself? Or is it not an app at all? *Can you say specifically what language course this is?*

Answer (score 0):

MPlayer cannot open ISO files (which are image files of a physical media).

What you need to do, is mount the .iso file on your system, so the "drive" becomes avaiable.

You can mount the file by right clicking on it choose "Open With" -> "Diskmounting Tool" (or something like that, I don't run an english version, so can't tell you for certain).

This should mount the file, so the system thinks it is a CD or DVD. Now you open the files from it, like you would any other CD or DVD.

VLC, should be able to open it, according to a comment below.

Comment: I've now tested MPlayer--like VLC, it plays video DVD ISOs. The problem is that this ISO image *isn't for a video DVD*. (This is confirmed by what the OP posted as an answer, which was then deleted altogether instead of being converted to an edit or comment, which would probably have been better. I've edited this info into the question.) Thus neither opening it in a video player, nor mounting it and attempting to play the mount as a DVD, will work. If the OP is trying to play video (I'm not sure even of that!), they must find the specific video files after mounting or extracting the ISO.